# How to remove fuse_hidden file when the running process can't be found?

Tags: hard-drive, uninstall, hidden-files, fuse

I have seen this issue in other threads but couldn't find a solution that worked for me.

So my fuse_hidden file (49GB) is in a trash directory on a protable hard-drive. I assume it stems from a unzip process with Archive Manager when I accidentally removed the drive.

```
sudo rm -rf .fuse_hidden000000080000fffa
```

Results in:

```
rm: cannot remove '.fuse_hidden000000080000fffa': Input/output error
```

I've also tried to find the process with `lsof` but it doesn't show any. It's just unlikely that there is still a process running considering that the file has been there for 2 months now. Also no luck deleting it on windows.

I don't really want to format the drive because of the ~1TB data that I currently can't put anywhere.

Does anyone have a solution?